# Should SharePoint Alerts automatically adjust for Daylight Savings Time changes?

Tags: alert, sharepoint-enterprise, date-time

We have a SP2010 farm that is up to the October CU.  After the time change, some users report that alerts that were sending out at 10am are now being sent at 9am.  I've googled a fair amount and found similar issues in 2007, suggesting it was fixed in hotfixes.  Looking at Timezone.xml, it looks like the configuration is correct.

I did find one suggestion that `stsadm -cmd updatealerts` be run to fixup a site's alerts, but this seems like something that should happen automatically.  So, should SharePoint Alerts automatically adjust for Daylight Savings Time changes?  If so, why could it be failing to do so in my farm?

Comment: I have the same issue. Anybody know how to fix this?